# UI testing vs unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, ui-testing

what is the different purpose of those both? I mean, in which condition I should do each of them?

as for the example condition. if you have the backend server and several front-end webs, which one you'll do?do-unit testing the backend server first or do-UI testing in the web UI first?
given the condition, the server and the front-end webs already exist, so it's not an iterative design to build along with (TDD)...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Unit testing aims to test small portions of your code (individual classes / methods) in isolation from the rest of the world.

UI testing may be a different name for system / functional / acceptance testing, where you test the whole system together to ensure it does what it is supposed to do under real life circumstances. (Unless by UI testing you mean usability / look & feel etc. testing, which is typically constrained to details on the UI.)

You need both of these in most of projects, but at different times: unit testing during development (ideally from the very beginning, [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) style), and UI testing somewhat later, once you actually have some complete end-to-end functionality to test.

If you already have the system running, but no tests, practically you have legacy code. Strive to get the best test coverage achievable with the least effort first, which means high level functional tests. Adding unit tests is needed too, but it takes much more effort and starts to pay back later.

Recommended reading: [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052).

Comment: And a fat +1 for referencing Working Effectively with Legacy Code.

Comment: What do you mean "high level functional tests"? Do you just mean UI Tests?

Answer (score 1):

Unit test should always be done. Unittests are there to provide proof that each UNIT (read: object) of your technical solution delivers the expected results. To put it very (maybe too) simple, user testing is there to  verify that your system fulfills the needs and demands of the user.

Answer (score 1):

Test pyramid [1] is important concept here, well described by Martin Fawler.
In short, tests that run end-to-end through the UI are: brittle and expensive to write. You may consider test recording tools [2] to speed recording and re-recording up. Disclaimer - I'm developer of such tool.

[1] https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html

[2] https://anwendo.com

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer, today I just came up with this question of why not just programmatically trigger layout functions and then unit-test your logic around that as well?

The answer I got from a senior dev was: programmatically trigger layout functions will not be an absolute copy of the real user-experience. In the real world, the system will trigger many callbacks, like when the user of an app backgrounds or foregrounds the app. Obviously you can trigger such events manually and test again, but would you be sure you got all events in all sequences right?!

The real user-experience is one where user makes actual network calls, taps on screens, loads multiple screen on top of each other and at times you might get system callbacks. Callbacks which you forgot to mock  that you didn't properly mock. In unit-tests you're mainly testing in isolation. In UI test, you setup the app, may have to login, etc. That stack you build is much more complex vs a unit-test. Hence it's better to not mix unit-testing with UI testing.